# How to use a custom element to wrap child custom elements into a div

Tags: javascript, dom, web-component, custom-element

I'm trying to create a wrapper Custom Element that wraps its child Custom Elements into a div.

But the child elements aren't wrapped. Instead, an empty div is inserted into the wrapper element before the child elements

```
<script>
  class ListItem extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = "<div>ListItem</div>";
    }
  }

  class List extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `<div class="list">${this.innerHTML}</div>`;
    }
  }

  customElements.define("list-item", ListItem);
  customElements.define("my-list", List);
</script>

<my-list>
  <list-item></list-item>
  <list-item></list-item>
  <list-item></list-item>
</my-list>
```

This is the result:

```
<my-list>
  <div class="list"></div>
  <list-item><div>ListItem</div></list-item>
  <list-item><div>ListItem</div></list-item>
  <list-item><div>ListItem</div></list-item>
</my-list>
```

I would have expected the following:

```
<my-list>
  <div class="list">
    <list-item><div>ListItem</div></list-item>
    <list-item><div>ListItem</div></list-item>
    <list-item><div>ListItem</div></list-item>
  </div>
</my-list>
```

You can try it out [here](https://codepen.io/quetzo/pen/rPxzZm).

Comment: It seems you're using another library or environment other than plain JS. What's the library you're using?

Comment: Not using any library, that's just plain JS [Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

Comment: I'm assuming you think that:  connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `<div class="list">${this.innerHTML}</div>`;
    } ..... Will result in the list-item to be within the list div? and you are trying to achieve that by calling   'customElements.define("list-item", ListItem);' just before   'customElements.define("my-list", List);' - was that your intention?

Comment: Thanks @Lynbarry - I need to get familiar with the class syntax!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's due to the parsing execution sequence. When the `<my-list>` tag is detected, it is created (and connected) immediately, before its children are inserted.

See issues addressed here [WICG Web Components Issue #809](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/809) and here [MDN `connectedCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements#using_the_lifecycle_callbacks#sect4).

As a consequent `${this.innerHTML}` will return an empty string in `connectedCallback()`.

You could wait for the children to be parsed, for example with the help of `setTimeout()`:

```
class List extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        setTimeout( () => 
            this.innerHTML = `<div class="list">${this.innerHTML}</div>` 
        )
    }
}
```

But you'd better use Shadow DOM with `<slot>` to insert elements of the light DOM:

```
class List extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
            .innerHTML = `<div class="list"><slot></slot></div>` 
    }
}
```

See the example below.

```js
class ListItem extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = "<div>ListItem</div>";
    }
}

class List extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
            .innerHTML = `<div class="list"><slot></slot></div>` 
    }
}

customElements.define("list-item", ListItem);
customElements.define("my-list", List);
```

```html
<my-list>
    <list-item></list-item>
    <list-item></list-item>
    <list-item></list-item>
</my-list>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to only use Custom Elements because I heard the Shadow Dom Polyfill maybe isn't up to scratch yet. Will look more thoroughly into it now, though.

Comment: @Lynbarry: As a developer and consumer of custom elements in all its iterations since nearly the beginning, the Shadow DOM polyfill is quite good. To be fair, though, unless you have to support IE11 (potentially lower), you don't even need it. My experience has been that the webcomponentsjs-loader is one of the best and works quite well in allowing your code to work quite consistently across IE11, Chrome, Edge, Safari, and Firefox. It fact, using it saves many more headaches than not using it. And, if you are using it, you have Shadow DOM. Way better than Shady DOM, IMHO.