# Web Components - wrap child elements

Tags: web-component

I have a web component which can have children. And on JS seeing it want it to wrap its current children inside of a modal tag (which already has a child).

I currently have:

```js
class Modal extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
         // Wrap current children inside of dialog element
    }
}
customElements.define("modal-component", Modal);
```

```html
<modal-component>
    <p> Lorem impsum </p>
</modal-component>

<!-- I want the logic in connectedCallback() to produce this with the p tag now being wrapped inside dialog -->
<modal-component>
    <dialog>
         <span class="close">&times;</span>
         <p> Lorem impsum </p>
    </dialog> 
</modal-component>
```

I tried writing this inside of `connectedCallback` but the value of `this.innerHTML` is `''` even when there are children

```js
this.innerHTML = `<dialog><span class="close">&times;</span>${this.innerHTML}</dialog>`;
```

I have tried using slots but that feature only seems to cover one to one injection when my `Modal` component must put multiple children into one slot.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a custom element to wrap child custom elements into a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369528/how-to-use-a-custom-element-to-wrap-child-custom-elements-into-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With slots you can insert multiple children:

```
connectedCallback() {
     this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
         .innerHTML = `<span class="close">&times;</span>
                 <slot></slot>`
}
```

Alternately, if you don't want to use `<slot>`, you need to make sure that the content of the custom element is parsed when you access the `innerHTML` property.

This can be achieved with either [`setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame`](http://anupbishnoi.com/2017/difference-between-setTimeout-setInterval-requestAnimationFrame/), or by defining the Custom Element after the HTML code is parsed (if it's possible):

```
<custom-element>...</custome-element>
<script>
  customElements.define( 'custom-element', ... )
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I found using `defer` or delaying the define call gave access to the elements children

Comment: @kaleidawave you're right, defer is also a possible solution